# $\lim f(t)^{g(t)} = 0^0 = 1$ if $f,g$ are analytic?

Tags: exponentiation, analytic-functions

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero#Continuous_exponents) that if $f,g$ are real analytic near $c$, and $f,g \to 0$ as $t \to c$, then along any path for which $f>0$ one has $f(t)^{g(t)} \to 1$. The proof Wikipedia cites is in German so I am not able to follow it. How does one show this?

Comment: Hint: real-analyticity implies that $f(x)=(x-c)^h k(x)$ and $g(x)=(x-c)^j \ell(x)$ where $h,j$ are positive integers and $k(x),\ell(x)$ are continuous and nonzero at $x=c$. Then show that $g(t)\log f(t)\to 0$ as $t\to c$. (The hypotheses allow $g(t)$ to be identically zero, for which this method doesn't work but then the result is trivial.)